# Is there way to execute any particular flow after every other flow without need to plug it explicitly

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I have multiple flows(To process message received from queue) to execute and after every flow I need to check if there is any error in previous flow, if yes, then I filter out the message in process, otherwise continue to next flow.

Currently, I have to plug this error handler flow explicitly after every other flow. Is there any way this can be done with some functionality where this error flow can be configured to run after every other flow. Or any other better way to do this?

Example:

flow 1 -> Validate message, if error, mark message as error

error flow -> check if message is marked error, if yes filter, otherwise continue.

flow 2 -> persist message to db, mark in case of error.

error flow -> check if message is marked error, if yes filter, otherwise continue

flow 3 -> and so on.

Or is there way to wrap (flow 1 + error flow), (flow 2 -> error flow) ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is exactly what you asked for, but I have sort of a solution. What can be done, is creating all flows, for instance we can look at:

```
val flows = Seq (
  Flow.fromFunction[Int, Int](x => { println(s"flow1: Received $x"); x * 2 }),
  Flow.fromFunction[Int, Int](x => { println(s"flow2: Received $x"); x + 1}),
  Flow.fromFunction[Int, Int](x => { println(s"flow3: Received $x"); x * x})
)
```

Then, we need to append to each of the exsiting flows, the error handling. So let's define it, and add it to each of the elements:

```
val errorHandling = Flow[Int].filter(_ % 2 == 0)
val errorsHandledFlows = flows.map(flow => flow.via(errorHandling))
```

Now, we need a helper function, that will connect all of our new flows:

```
def connectFlows(errorsHandledFlows: Seq[Flow[Int, Int, _]]): Flow[Int, Int, _] = {
  errorsHandledFlows match {
    case Seq() => Flow[Int] // This line is actually redundant, But I don't want to have an unexhausted pattern matching
    case Seq(singleFlow) => singleFlow
    case head :: tail => head.via(connectFlows(tail))
  }
}
```

And now, we need to execute all together, for example:

```
Source(1 to 4).via(connectFlows(errorsHandledFlows)).to(Sink.foreach(println)).run()
```

Will provide the output:

```
flow1: Received 1
flow2: Received 2
flow1: Received 2
flow2: Received 4
flow1: Received 3
flow2: Received 6
flow1: Received 4
flow2: Received 8
```

As you can tell, we filter the odd numbers. Therefore the first flow gets all numbers from 1 to 4. The second flow received 2,4,6,8 (the first flow multiplied the values by 2), and the last one did not receive any flow, because the second flow makes all of the values odd.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Apologies, I did not mention it in question, but I have non linear flows (e.g. use of broadcast, split, etc). I am just curious on how can I make it work in such scenarios. Please note, I am using akka javadsl library..

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Merge

```scala
val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val merge = builder.add(Merge[Int](3))

  val flow1 = ...
  val flow2 = ...
  val flow3 = ...

  flow1 ~> merge
  flow2 ~> merge
  flow3 ~> merge

  ClosedShape
})
```

Not sure if it meets your need, just showing the alternative.